# How to prove the determinant of this matrix invoving two sets of numbers is greater than zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, determinant

Suppose $0<a_1<a_2<\cdots <a_n$,$\lambda_1<\lambda_2<\cdots<\lambda_n$and
\begin{align*}
A=\left({a_i}^{\lambda_j}\right)=
\begin{pmatrix}
{a_1}^{\lambda_1}&{a_1}^{\lambda_2}&\ldots &{a_1}^{\lambda_n}\\
{a_2}^{\lambda_1}&{a_2}^{\lambda_2}&\ldots &{a_2}^{\lambda_n}\\
\vdots &\vdots&\ldots&\vdots\\
{a_n}^{\lambda_1}&{a_n}^{\lambda_2}&\ldots &{a_n}^{\lambda_n}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*} 
Prove that the determinant of A is greater than zero,$\mathrm{i,e.}$ $\det A>0$.

It is easy to check that the assertion is true when $n=2$,for when $n=2$,
\begin{align*}
\det A&=\begin{vmatrix}
{a_1}^{\lambda_1}&{a_1}^{\lambda_2}\\
{a_2}^{\lambda_1}&{a_2}^{\lambda_2}
\end{vmatrix}
={a_1}^{\lambda_1}{a_2}^{\lambda_2}-{a_1}^{\lambda_2}{a_2}^{\lambda_1}\\
&=\exp\{\lambda_1\ln a_1+\lambda_2 \ln a_2\}-\exp\{\lambda_2\ln a_1+\lambda_1 \ln a_2\}
\end{align*}
Since $(\lambda_1\ln a_1+\lambda_2 \ln a_2)-(\lambda_2\ln a_1+\lambda_1 \ln a_2)=(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)
(\ln a_2-\ln a_1)>0$,then the case for $n=2$holds.While about the general case for $n>2$,I have no idea.
Can anyone help me?It's a homework.

Comment: Just a quick thought: maybe induction together with some calculations using Vandermonde determinants will work...

Comment: Yes , I had ever thought about it,while the progress is hard for me .Carrying out the expansion of the determinant according to a line is awful.

Comment: I think I have got some new idea from your comment!I will try to forcus on${a_1}^{\lambda_1}$,and convert the other number in the line and column to zero by elementary transformation,then use induction.

Comment: A proof can be found in Theorem 6.5.2, pp.297-299 of Kung et al., *Combinatorics: The Rota Way*, Cambridge University Press. The proof itself is not technically difficult, but IMHO it's rather difficult to come up with an idea to solve the problem. I'm surprised that this was passed to you as a homework.